# wget invalid encode in c

Tags: c, wget

i would like to download a webpage with wget in c.
i've wrote this code but when i try it, the program download the pages named with only a part of the given name and i found in the filename an invalid encoding.

the page name is like this

```
test0L���i}�X�����L�������R�td]�{��+`��U{�@ (invalid encoding)
```

the important part of my program is this.

```
#define PAGE "http://deckbox.org/games/mtg/cards?p="

char *cat_url(char *s1, char *s2)
{
    char *tmp;
    tmp = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char*) * (strlen(s1) + strlen(s2)));
    strcat(tmp, s1);
    strcat(tmp, s2);
    return tmp;
}

void get_card_name(char *pg_name)
{
    int i;
    int fk;
    char *args[6], tmp;

    for (i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
        tmp = itoa(i);
        args[0] = "wget";
        args[1] = "-q";
        args[2] = cat_url(PAGE, &tmp);
        args[3] = "-O";
        args[4] = cat_url("test", &tmp);
        args[5] = NULL;

        if (fork()) {
            wait(&fk);
        } else {
            if (execvp(args[0], args) == -1) {
               error_rep("ERROR.\n");
            }
       }
    }
}
```

how can i fix the trouble?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is with the following lines:

```
char tmp;
tmp = itoa(i);
```

Please try the following instead:

```
char tmp[2];   // to store 1 char and '\0'
...
snprintf (tmp, sizeof (tmp), "%d", i);   // portable way to convert int to string
...
args[2] = cat_url(PAGE, tmp); // tmp is a pointer now
...
args[4] = cat_url("test", tmp);
```

Hope it helps !

Answer (score 5):

I think you need to use `strcpy()` for the `s1` in `cat_url()`, like this

```
strcpy(tmp, s1);
```

...also the `sizeof()` is for a pointer and not the destination type `char` plus adding one char for the zero-termination. Maybe something like this

```
char *cat_url(char *s1, char *s2)
{
    char *tmp;
    tmp = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*(strlen(s1) + strlen(s2) + 1)); // sizeof char and not pointer
    strcpy(tmp, s1); // strcpy here
    strcat(tmp, s2);
    return tmp;
}
```

Also Wizzard answer has an important point about `itoa()` and usage of its result.

...and as a last note, there is a memory leak as `args[2]` and `argc[4]` should be `free()`'d after they are used. You can also consider moving the whole `args` array into the else part of the of statement as it is not used in the if part.

Comment: Note that sizeof(char) is one by definition in the C Standard. Multiplying with it is more paranoia than necessary. :-)